# History Api запоминает только результат ajax-запроса

Tags: ajax, history-api, history

```
var counter = 1;

$('button').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.json',
            method: 'GET',
            success: function(res){

                $('body').append(JSON.stringify(res))

                if (!!(window.history && history.pushState)) {
                    history.replaceState(null, null, '?page=' + counter);
                }

                counter++;

            }
        });
    });
```

На сайте вылез косяк, связанный с тем что по нажатию на кнопку происходит подгрузка данных через ajax и обновляется история браузера через history api через метод replaceState, который перезаписывает истории.

Проблема в том что если я нажимаю кнопку назад  - то показывается не предыдущая страница , а результат ajax запроса. То есть в историю как будто записывается результат ajax, хотя url при этом корректный

Это в chrome, в FF отлично работает и я вижу всю страницу.
Попробовал воспроизвести на отдельно html-страничке - все гуд во всех браузерах - кто нибудь сталкивался с таким?

Если меняешь GET запрос на POST, то все гуд

Как будто история запоминает этот запрос GET запрос (воспроизводиться только в chrome)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дело было в *ajax*. Он кеширует get запросы. Помог `cache: false`